# Why it's not possible to get the Runnable embedded in a Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, runnable

As far as I can understand from the [`java.lang.Thread`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) docs, and from other questions posted here on stackoverflow, like "[How to access a Runnable object by Thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300579/how-to-access-a-runnable-object-by-thread)" and "[Get current instance of Runnable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021809/get-current-instance-of-runnable)" it's not possible to get a reference of the `Runnable` object embedded in a `Thread`.

A scenario where having this possibility would be useful is when implementing a method, whose signature can't be modified because we are overriding a method defined in another class or interface, and different operations are required to be performed depending on the type of `Runnable` embedded in the current `Thread`.

If we had for example a method called `getRunnable` in the `Thread` class we could do something like this:

```
if (Thread.currentThread().getRunnable() instanceof Type1) {
  // do something...
} else {
  // do something else...
}
```

This could be useful also in situations when we want to ensure the operations contained in a method are executed only by certain threads and not by others.

So I was wondering, is there a specific reason why the Java developers decided to not allow to get the `Runnable` instance from a `Thread`, or is it be a missing feature worth to be notified? If you think there is no reason behind that choice but it's not worth to notify it as missing feature, what strategy would you use in the scenario described above?

Comment: What would be the "runnable" for the main thread with the `main` method?

Comment: Branching on the result of `instanceof` like you do in your example is almost never a good idea.

Comment: I'm not going to offer this as an answer as it would be intensive but hey. You can look into using the threads stack trace. `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()`.

Comment: I dunno the reason, but alternatively you may also extend the Thread class, and keep a reference to your Runnable object in your subclass and provide a getter method to get the Runnable back when needed.

Comment: @aix, thanks, care to elaborate?

Comment: Not all `Thread` instances _have_ a runnable, no?

Comment: Your usage of runnable is entirely out of scope for the Thread class. Even if the developers of Thread knew about your idea, they would decide not to support it.

Comment: @LouisWasserman true, in that case the returned value would be `null`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik what solution would you suggest to solve the need in the scenario I pointed out?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> So I was wondering, is there a specific reason why the Java developers decided to not allow to get the Runnable instance from a Thread

It was probably just not a requirement.  The `Runnable` itself should be able to identify its own class so the idea that it needs to get that information is strange.  It could also be a protection so that other threads would not have access to the class being running in another thread.

If you need access to the current `Runnable` from other parts of your application then I'd recommend using a `ThreadLocal<Runnable>`. In your `run()` method you could set it and then retrieve it in your other classes. You'd need to put the `ThreadLocal` somewhere globally accessible however.

You could also process the current stack trace to figure out the enclosing `Runnable` class which is even more of a hack but it would work.

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple approaches you could take to get around this:

Keep a mapping of your `Runnable`s to the `Thread`s that are executing them (either with a `Map<Thread, Runnable>` or with a `ThreadLocal<Runnable>`)
Use reflection to access the `Runnable` from the `Thread`:

```
private static final Field target;
static {
    Field f = null;
    try {
        f = Thread.class.getDeclaredField("target");
        f.setAccessible(true);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        // might happen in a different version of Java (works in Java 7)
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    target = f;
}

public static Runnable getTarget(Thread t) {
    try {
        return (Runnable) target.get(t);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // shouldn't happen, we already made the field accessible when we created it
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a indirect method may be it will help, You can get the stack trace.

```
StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElement = thread.getStackTrace();
for(StackTraceElement e :stackTraceElement){
   System.out.println("Trace "+e.getClassName());
}
```

Output :

Trace java.lang.Thread

**Trace com.emc.multithreading.RunnableDemo**

Trace java.lang.Thread